# In Supergirl, does Alex have telekinesis?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

In The CW network's [*Supergirl* TV series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergirl_(TV_series)), [Season 4 Episode 17](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Supergirl_episodes#Season_4_(2018%E2%80%9319)) is entitle "All About Eve" and originally aired 2019-03-31.

In an action scene about two thirds of the way through, it appeared to me that a gun moved into Alex's hand.  Did I miss something in past episodes about how she came to have that ability?  If the explanation comes later, please don't elaborate.

Comment: Wasn’t it magnets in her suit? She got some kind of upgraded suit that gave her some abilities ISTR.

Comment: Yes, according to ErikM's answer....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, what you saw was a function of Alex's suit.
The [Arrowverse wiki](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Alex_Danvers%27s_suit) lists the abilities the suit possesses, the one in question being;

> **Magnets:** The suit's gloves are magnetic, which allow Alex to pull her weapons towards her if disarmed. She has also used the magnets in the suit to make a magnetic shield to defend herself or to contain explosives.

The suit makes it's first appearance in the season 3 episode Trinity. The magnetic function is explained and demonstrated around the 1:45 mark here;

Comment: Can you offer any evidence other than the wiki?

Comment: Wiki isn't always reliable. Could you provide actual evidence other than fan pages/wikis?

Comment: Edited into the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  Sometimes, the details escape me.....